# Generate Dynamic HTML page based on clicks in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have multiple links in table. Each row represents a link. I want to redirect the link into another page for its description. To implement it, I want to use a common template where based on the clicked link, dynamically the HTML page will be filled with the information. The url needs to be dynamic too, appended by the clicked value. All these needs to be implemented in flask framework.

---

Eg: http://bearch.herokuapp.com/query
Whenever I click more, it should redirect to another HTML page which should be dynamic, instead of hardcoded as in case of http://bearch.herokuapp.com/100YearsofSolitude
All clicks should send a request and response from the server should be dynamic HTML page based on the clicked link. The url should also be generated based on the clicked link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can embed the item identifier in links

```
<a href="/items/item1">item 1</a>
```

and in route you can extract the identifier

```
@app.route('/items/<item_identifier>')
def show_item_info(item_identifier):
    print item_identfier
    # query the db for item and assign it item 
    # pass the item to template
    return render_template('item.html',item=item)
```

here item.html is the generic template for each item  and you can now render it by template expressions ex {{ item.description }}

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Appreciate your help. Kudos.